# TinyMCE - local image upload

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I get a strange bug when uploading a local image to TinyMCE form every time - the page reloads. Using **TinyMCE 4.7.13** and **ASP MVC**.

My code:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '.formatedtext',
    branding: false,
    plugins: 'code,emoticons,lists,advlist,autolink,autoresize,autosave,codesample,textcolor,colorpicker,fullscreen,hr,image,link,media,preview,searchreplace,table,textpattern,wordcount,imagetools',
    toolbar: 'image,code,emoticons,bulllist,numlist,restoredraft,codesample,forecolor,backcolor,fullscreen,preview,searchreplace',
    width: '100%',
    language: 'cs',
    browser_spellcheck: true,
    image_advtab: true,
    paste_data_images: true,
    automatic_uploads: true,
    file_picker_types: 'image',
    images_upload_url: '/TinyMce/TinyMceUpload'
});
```

Action in TinyMce controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TinyMceUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file) {
    //Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    string loc = SaveFile(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/UsersContent/"), file);

    return Json(new {
        location = loc
    });
}
```

Where `SaveFile` is defined and working.

The problem is that the image is loaded, saved successfully but once loaded the page reloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index.cshtml

```
    <script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea",
            theme: "modern",
            paste_data_images: true,
            plugins: [
                "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
                "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
                "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
            ],
            toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
            toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
            image_advtab: true,
            file_picker_callback: function (callback, value, meta) {
                if (meta.filetype == 'image') {
                    $('#upload').trigger('click');
                    $('#upload').on('change', function () {
                        var file = this.files[0];
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                            callback(e.target.result, {
                                alt: ''
                            });
                        };
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    });
                }
            },

        });

    </script>
```

and direct display in the textarea image in Base64 Encoder if you upload image

Comment: No, file_picker_callback is depraced